# Array of derived type: select array entry

Tags: arrays, fortran, derived-types

In the following program I define an array of derived variables, which have two properties, A and B. I would like to have a subroutine that performs some function (e.g. calculate the gradient or max or min) on a property A or B. Properties A and B are arrays as well.

```
  1       module example
  2          implicit none
  3          type array 
  4              real :: A(2) ! property A
  5              real :: B(2) ! property B
  6          end type array
  7       contains
  8          subroutine use_property(C1,C2)
  9              implicit none
 10              real :: C1(2),C2(2)
 11              !Function involving A or B
 12          end subroutine use_property
 13       end module example
 14 !-----------------------------------
 15       program test
 16          use example
 17          implicit none
 18          type(array) :: grid(2)
 19
 20          call use_property(grid(1)%A,grid(2)%A)
 21          call use_property(grid(1)%B,grid(2)%B)
 22       end
```

The previous code works well. However, if the length of the variable "grid" increases by 3 then calling the subroutine would require something like:

```
 use_property(grid(1)%B,grid(2)%B,grid(3)%B,grid(4)%B,grid(5)%B).
```

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to achieve the same result of applying a function to a specific element of an array of derived variables.

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. Can't you make your function accept an array?

Comment: Replace `use_property(grid(1)%B,grid(2)%B,grid(3)%B,grid(4)%B,grid(5)%B)` by `use_property(grid%B)`. Either do as @VladimirF has suggested and write a function which takes an array as argument, or have a look at elemental procedures.

Comment: The above code is a simplified case of a more complicated problem where the components of the derived variable are not vectors but arrays that differ in size. Moreover the variable grid might have another property, D, which I don't want to apply the subroutine to. So for example, the derived variable grid has the following components (grid%A(3,6), grid%B(100,33,9), grid%D(6)). Calling the subroutine by use_property(grid%B) returns an error (A component cannot be an array if the encompassing structure is an array). As for the elemental procedures I am not sure how it apply in this case.